# React Redux Axios: POST Request not receiving credentials from redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have been working on authentication with my project. I have a REST api backend that serves JWT tokens. My front end stack is ReactJS, Redux, Axios and Redux Thunk.

**My question is why when I submit my form it does not send any credentials?**

But when I console log the action and payload on *credChange* it seems to be correct. Am I not setting the state somewhere? 
Also, axios does not catch the 400 Bad Request error.

Here is my code:

**AuthActions.js**

```
export const credChange = ({ prop, value }) => {
  return {
    type: CRED_CHANGE,
    payload: { prop, value },
  };
};
export const logoutUser = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_USER });
  };
};
const loginSuccess = (dispatch, response) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: response.data.token,
  });
};
const loginError = (dispatch, error) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_ERROR,
    payload: error.response.data,
  });
};
export const loginUser = ({ empNum, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles_api/jwt/authTK/',
      data: {
        emp_number: empNum,
        password,
      },
    })
      .then(response => loginSuccess(dispatch, response))
      .catch(error => loginError(dispatch, error));
  };
};
```

**AuthReducer.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  empNum: '',
  password: '',
  empNumErr: null,
  passwordErr: null,
  authTK: null,
  loading: false,
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CRED_CHANGE:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value };
    case LOGIN_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...INITIAL_STATE,
        loading: true,
      };
    case LOGOUT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        INITIAL_STATE,
      };
    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...INITIAL_STATE,
        authTK: action.payload,
      };
    case LOGIN_USER_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...INITIAL_STATE,
        empNumErr: action.payload.emp_number,
        passwordErr: action.payload.password,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**LoginForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {
  credChange,
  loginUser,
  logoutUser,
} from '../Actions';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.renderEmpNumErr = this.renderEmpNumErr.bind(this);
    this.empNumChange = this.empNumChange.bind(this);
    this.passwordChange = this.passwordChange.bind(this);
  }
  onFormSubmit() {
    const { empNum, password } = this.props;
    this.props.loginUser({ empNum, password });
  }
  empNumChange(text) {
    this.props.credChange({ prop: 'empNum', value: text.target.value });
  }
  passwordChange(text) {
    this.props.credChange({ prop: 'password', value: text.target.value });
  }
  renderEmpNumErr() {
    if (this.props.empNumErr) {
      return (
        <p>
          {this.props.empNumErr}
        </p>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="numberLabel">Employee Number</label>
          <input
            id="numberLabel"
            type="password"
            value={this.props.empNum}
            onChange={this.empNumChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="passLabel">Password</label>
          <input
            id="passLabel"
            type="password"
            value={this.props.password}
            onChange={this.passwordChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        {this.renderEmpNumErr()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ counter }) => {
  const {
    empNum,
    password,
    loading,
    empNumErr,
    passwordErr,
    authTK,
  } = counter;
  return {
    empNum,
    password,
    loading,
    empNumErr,
    passwordErr,
    authTK,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { credChange, loginUser, logoutUser })(LoginForm);
```

**After Submitting form with credentials**

The console says:

*POST XHR http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles_api/jwt/authTK/ [HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request 5ms]*

And the POST request Raw Data is blank, therefore no credentials were sent.

{"emp_number":["This field is required."],"password":["This field is required."]}

***EDIT***
If there is any other information I can provide please say so but I think this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like empNum and password aren't getting set in the state. This is because the action object returned by credChange doesn't get dispatched, so the reducer never get called:

```
// dispatch calls the reducer which updates the state
dispatch(actionCreator())

// returns an action object, doesn't call reducer
actionCreator()
```

You can dispatch actions automatically by calling a *bound* action creator:

```
// calls the reducer, updates the state
const boundActionCreator = () => {dispatch(actionCreator())}

// call boundActionCreator in your component
boundActionCreator()
```

mapDispatchToProps can be used to define bound action creators (to be passed as props):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

  return {
      credChange: ({ prop, value }) => {dispatch(credChange({prop, value})},
      loginUser: ({ empNum, password }) => {dispatch(loginUser({empNum, password})},
      logoutUser: () => {dispatch(logoutUser()},
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

This should solve the state update issue, allowing props that read from state (empNumber, password, etc.) to update as well.

Comment: loginUser is being dispatched. onFormSubmit() dispatches it. This is verified because the axios request will go through. The problem is the credentials are empty. I just need to figure out why, when the axios request is called, the values that should be in empNum and password are blank. This is obviously not the expected behavior. Any ideas?
**Edit**

Maybe I am wrong and I am still missing something. If so can you elaborate? @GraysonLangford

Comment: Your answer led me into the right direction. I ended up making empNum and password update on component level state and then onSubmit dispatched the action to login with the credentials. This is working but is it the best option? I ask because the auth system I built on the backend uses JWT and I intend to make login timout and refresh capability. Maybe keeping credentials on redux state is the way to go to refresh login, etc.. @GraysonLangford

Comment: This thread may answer your question: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287

If empNum and password aren't needed elsewhere, better to keep them in local component state. If later you find that other components need to access them (and passing as props is impossible or requires passing down too many levels), could always move back to global redux state.

Comment: You were very helpful @Grayson Langford! Thank you. The thread you pointed me to answered my question. I just have to take the time to understand the way react and redux work together. Thank you for your answers I will check your answer as the correct one in hopes that this will help others down the road. Cheers.